# FastAPI: Having a dependency through Depends() and a schema refer to the same root level key without ending up with multiple body parameters

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a situation where I want to authorize the active user against one of the values (`Organization`) in a FastAPI route. When an object of a particular type is being submitted, one of the keys (`organization_id`) should be present and the user should be verified as having access to the organization.

I've solved this as a dependency in the API signature to avoid having to replicate this code across all routes that needs access to this property:

```
def get_organization_from_body(organization_id: str = Body(None),
                               user: User = Depends(get_authenticated_user),
                               organization_service: OrganizationService = Depends(get_organization_service),
                               ) -> Organization:
    if not organization_id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Missing organization_id.')

    organization = organization_service.get_organization_for_user(organization_id, user)

    if not organization:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail='Organization authorization failed.')

    return organization
```

This works fine, and if the API endpoint expects an organization through an `organization_id` key in the request, I can get the organization directly populated by introducing `get_organization_from_body` as a dependency in my route:

```
@router.post('', response_model=Bundle)
async def create_bundle([...]
                        organization: Organization = Depends(get_organization_from_body),
                        ) -> Model:
```

.. and if the user doesn't have access to the organization, an 403 exception is raised.

However, I also want to include my actual object *on the root level* through a schema model. So my first attempt was to make a JSON request as:

```
{
  'name': generated_name,
  'organization_id': created_organization['id_key']
}
```

And then adding my incoming Pydantic model:

```
@router.post('', response_model=Bundle)
async def create_bundle(bundle: BundleCreate,
                        organization: Organization = Depends(get_organization_from_body),
                        [...]
                        ) -> BundleModel:
    [...]
    return bundle
```

The result is the same whether the pydantic model / schema contains `organization_id` as a field or not:

```
class BundleBase(BaseModel):
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class BundleCreate(BundleBase):
    organization_id: str
    client_id: Optional[str]
```

.. but when I introduce my `get_organization_from_body` dependency, FastAPI sees that I have another dependency that refers to a Body field, and the description of the `bundle` object has to be moved inside a `bundle` key instead (so instead of "validating" the `organization_id` field, the JSON layout needs to change - and since I feel that `organization_id` is part of the `bundle` description, it should live there .. if possible).

The error message tells me that `bundle` was expected as a separate field:

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'bundle'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

And rightly so, when I move `name` inside a `bundle` key instead:

```
{
    'bundle': {
        'name': generated_name,
    },
    'organization_id': created_organization['id_key']
}
```

.. my test passes and the request is successful.

This might be slightly bike shedding, but if there's a quick fix to work around this limitation in any way I'd be interested to find a way to both achieve validation (either through `Depends()` or in some alternative way without doing it explicitly in each API route function that requires that functionality) and a flat JSON layout that matches my output format closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to FastAPI `0.53.2`, dependencies for the body were resolved the way you are trying to do. Such code:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    val_1: int
    val_2: int


def get_val_1(val_1: int = Body(..., embed=True)):
     return val_1


@app.post("/item", response_model=Item)
def handler(full_body: Item, val_1: int = Depends(get_val_1)):
    return full_body
```

Expected such body:

```
{
    "val_1": 0,
    "val_2": 0
}
```

But [starting from](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/1079) version `0.53.2`, different body dependencies are automatically embedded (`embed=True`) and the code above expects the following body:

```
{
  "full_body": {
    "val_1": 0,
    "val_2": 0
  },
  "val_1": 0
}
```

Now, in order to have access to the model for the whole body and to have access to its elements as a separate dependency, you need to use same dependency for the body model everywhere:

```
def get_val_1(full_body: Item):
    return full_body.val_1


@app.post("/item", response_model=Item)
def handler(full_body: Item, val_1: int = Depends(get_val_1)):
    return full_body
```

#### Update for shared dependency

You can share one body dependency for multiple models, but in this case, two conditions must be met: the names of the dependencies must be the same and their types must be compatible (through inheritance or not). Example below:

```
class Base(BaseModel):
    val_1: int


class NotBase(BaseModel):
    val_1: int


class Item1(Base):
    val_2: int


class Item2(Base):
    val_3: int


def get_val1_base(full_body: Base):
     return full_body.val_1


def get_val1_not_base(full_body: NotBase):
    return full_body.val_1


@app.post("/item1", response_model=Item1)
def handler(full_body: Item1, val_1: int = Depends(get_val1_base)):
    return full_body


@app.post("/item2", response_model=Item2)
def handler(full_body: Item2, val_1: int = Depends(get_val1_not_base)):
    return full_body
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My hope was to re-use the dependency that resolves and validate the dependency for multiple different schemas (such as `Item` here), where the same field name is used to represent the dependent object (so a `DifferentItem` that also contains a `val_1` property). I haven't tried it yet, but would a Mixin to the `Item` and `DifferentItem` classes work, where the `get_val_1` has a dependency on the Mixin class instead of the actual Item class? (i.e. would FastAPI consider the inheritance hierarchy?)

Comment: Yes you can share one dependency for different models. I've updated the answer. But I'm not fully sure that this approach will work in all future versions.

Comment: That seems like a possible solution. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work without two distinct base classes and through Mixins instead, but I've accepted the answer. I'll award the bounty as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: There is only one base class here, the second is *not base* and is given for completeness.